# how high a current should flow through a device to destroy it

Tags: voltage, current, batteries

I have learnt that cells connected in parallel should be nearly identical in voltage to prevent one cell from destroying the other through high currents. Can anyone explain in depth?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

> CAN ANYONE EXPLAIN IN DEPTH.

No. This sounds as though you are looking for someone to write an essay for you for your homework.

There isn't a lot of depth required. Here is the basic idea. You can do your own research based on this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxlGun.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Equivalent circuit for two batteries connected in parallel. Internal series resistances are shown.*

The current that flows in this circuit will be that caused by the difference in voltages between the batteries and will be limited by the sum of the series resistances.